# Поиск по денормализованным данным

Tags: база-данных, архитектура

Есть некоторая сущность типа "конференция", в которой могут оказаться несколько участников с разными тегами:

```
{
  "participants": {
    "a": "79219998877",
    "b": "79219998878",
    "c": "79219998879"
  }
}
```

Мне необходимо хранить эти данные в БД (конкретный движок сейчас неважен - он, вероятнее всего, сменится через некоторое время - считаем, что нет ни джойнов, ни индексации полей-массивов) и производить по ним поиск - мне надо получать конференции, удовлетворяющие произвольному количеству условий "`a` был `79219998877`", "`b` был `79219998878`" и аналогам, `a` и `b` при этом могут оказаться абсолютно произвольными тегами. Можно ли как-то представить эти данные в каком-то виде (без полей-массивов и джойнов), позволяющем производить подобный поиск простой выборкой, или это в приницпе невозможно?

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что нужно всегда получать последнюю конференцию по двум заданным участникам? или кол-во может быть абсолютно произвольно

Comment: @KoVadim произвольно. В данный момент требуется искать только по одному и по двум, но я ищу серебряную пулю, построить view / дополнительную таблицу для конкретных случаев вполне могу, но вся эта морока из-за того, что проект уже пришел на рефакторинг и хочется защититься от всего, от чего только можно и предоставить конечному пользователю произвольные возможности для поиска.

Comment: а вам подойдет только JSON или данные можно переделать под XML?

Comment: @Mirdin это просто описание структуры данных. Хранить в виде массива (неважно, в каком контейнере) пока, скорее всего, не получится.

Comment: @Etki - вам не надо хранить в виде массива, храните либо в виде кусочков JSON или XML, с которыми современные БД вполне могут работать (например с помощью xquery в MSSQL): фильтровать, выбирать нужные сущности

Comment: @Mirdin под контейнерами я подразумевал именно JSON и XML. Кассандра, на которую собираюсь мигрировать через некоторое время (с полным сохранением схемы) не умеет с ними работать (и не должна).

Comment: @Etki кому награду присуждать? Или фифти-фифти?

Comment: @andreycha тут на ваше усмотрение скорее. У darigaaz очень масштабный ответ

Answer (score 3):

У вас некорректная постановка задачи.

> Как мне хранить такие данные, чтобы быстро и безболезненно осуществлять поиск по произвольному количеству участников?

Но при этом

> Мне необходимо хранить эти данные в БД (конкретный движок сейчас неважен - он, вероятнее всего, сменится через некоторое время - считаем, что нет ни джойнов, ни индексации полей-массивов) и производить по ним поиск.

Ответ будет зависеть от типа БД, которую вы выберите.
Самый "безболезненный" вариант - храните все в JSON и Filter вам в помощь. Но такой самый простой вариант вас, скорее всего, не устроит, потому что есть еще другие данные, которые будет неудобно хранить в таком виде и болезненно использовать.

При выборе NoSQL хранилища у вас почти полный контроль над данными и выборкой, но за это сами следите за консистентностью данных. Но зато можете применять любой Filter, который выберет нужные вам записи. И если дальше в проекте у вас будут сущность с большим количеством связей, то можно замучаться следить за ними.

В случае реляционной БД, все сложнее, потому что на сложность фильтра ложатся ограничения реляционной алгебры, зато все в порядке с консистентностью и выборке по индексу.

Фильтр из примера можно реализовать чем то типа: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b891f

```
  SELECT Conference.conf_id, COUNT(Conference.conf_id) as cnt
  FROM Conference
  JOIN Participants
  ON Conference.conf_id = Participants.conf_id
  AND (Participants.key, Participants.val) IN (
    ('a', '79219998878'),
    ('b', '79219998877')
  )

  GROUP BY (Conference.conf_id)
  HAVING cnt = 2
```

Если что-то более сложное, то скорее всего ограничения реляционной алгебры не позволят вам это сделать. Но и из этой ситуации есть, как вам подсказали, выход - хранить вашу структуру JSON'ом и накладывать условие на выборку

```
SELECT *
FROM Conf
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(json_field, "79219998877", "$.a") AND JSON_CONTAINS(json_field, "79219998878", "$.b")

-- или через виртуальные колонки
-- WHERE json_field->"$.a" = "79219998877" AND json_field->"$.b" = "79219998878"
```

[виртуальные колонки](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html)

Так вы получите гибрид обоих миров, но доступно только в MySQL > 5.7. Там даже можно [индексы](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html#create-table-secondary-indexes-virtual-columns) строить.

UDP: напомнили про postgres, спасибо
Да, там тоже есть подобный функционал с jsonb и тоже можно по полю строить [запросы](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html). Смотрите @> и <@ операторы.

**UDP: после прочтения комментов, мне более менее стало ясно, что имелось в виду**

> В данный момент проект сидит на реляционке, в будущем планируется переход на row-column хранилище (NoSQL - это далеко не только json-подобные хранилища), которая предполагает подготовку данных для простых запросов в "плоском" виде, и в котором я не смогу искать по части ассоциативного массива (только по полной версии). Отсюда произрастает вышеописанный вопрос, который сводится не к поиску обходных решений, а к тому, можно ли как-то представить все это в подготовленном виде.

В данном случае "обходное" решение это своя собственная реализация индекса по массиву документов.
Но написание "своего" такого индексатора - задача очень сложная.

Вы же не сможете встроить этот индексатор в свою БД. А его реализация на php/ruby/python, скорее всего, будет уступать по производительности полному перебору в базе. Значит придется писать его на "системном" языке и общаться посредством IPC/socket.

Тогда способ как им пользоваться я вижу так: при создании/удалении документа вы будете передавать индексатору этот документ, а он будет на этом основании изменять индекс. Потом когда вам потребуется выборка, вы делаете к нему запрос, а вам он быстренько возвращает ID элементов удовлетворяющих этому запросу, и уже с этими ID вы лезете в базу и выбираете записи. Тогда зачем изобретать этот велосипед, если можно поднять какую-нить MongoDB и пользоваться ей точно так же.

Дальше пример для Mongo.

Документы хранить лучше в виде:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("571923c7e4b08c60be5228a4"),
        "id" : 1,
        "participants" : [
                {
                        "key" : "a",
                        "value" : "79219998878"
                },
                {
                        "key" : "b",
                        "value" : "79219998877"
                },
                {
                        "key" : "c",
                        "value" : "79219998879"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("571923f0e4b08c60be5228a9"),
        "id" : 2,
        "participants" : [
                {
                        "key" : "a",
                        "value" : "79219998877"
                },
                {
                        "key" : "b",
                        "value" : "79219998878"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("57193370e4b08c60be522acb"),
        "id" : 3,
        "participants" : [
                {
                        "key" : "a",
                        "value" : "79219998877"
                },
                {
                        "key" : "c",
                        "value" : "79219998879"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("571933c2e4b08c60be522ad4"),
        "id" : 4,
        "participants" : [
                {
                        "key" : "a",
                        "value" : "79219998878"
                },
                {
                        "key" : "b",
                        "value" : "79219998877"
                },
                {
                        "key" : "d",
                        "value" : "79219998873"
                }
        ]
}
```

Сделать индекс:

```
db.participants.createIndex({ "participants.key" : 1 , "participants.value" : 1})
```

И искать:

```
db.participants.find( 
{                                                              
        "participants" : {                                     
                "$all" : [                                     
                        {                                      
                                "$elemMatch" : {               
                                        "key" : "a",           
                                        "value" : "79219998878"
                                }                              
                        },                                     
                        {                                      
                                "$elemMatch" : {               
                                        "key" : "b",           
                                        "value" : "79219998877"
                                }                              
                        }                                      
                ]                                              
        }                                                      
}    ).pretty()
```

Вывод

```
{                                                                                                                                                                                                
        "_id" : ObjectId("571923c7e4b08c60be5228a4"),                                                                                                                                            
        "id" : 1,                                                                                                                                                                                
        "participants" : [                                                                                                                                                                       
                {                                                                                                                                                                                
                        "key" : "a",                                                                                                                                                             
                        "value" : "79219998878"                                                                                                                                                  
                },                                                                                                                                                                               
                {                                                                                                                                                                                
                        "key" : "b",                                                                                                                                                             
                        "value" : "79219998877"                                                                                                                                                  
                },                                                                                                                                                                               
                {                                                                                                                                                                                
                        "key" : "c",                                                                                                                                                             
                        "value" : "79219998879"                                                                                                                                                  
                }                                                                                                                                                                                
        ]                                                                                                                                                                                        
}                                                                                                                                                                                                
{                                                                                                                                                                                                
        "_id" : ObjectId("571933c2e4b08c60be522ad4"),                                                                                                                                            
        "id" : 4,                                                                                                                                                                                
        "participants" : [                                                                                                                                                                       
                {                                                                                                                                                                                
                        "key" : "a",                                                                                                                                                             
                        "value" : "79219998878"                                                                                                                                                  
                },                                                                                                                                                                               
                {                                                                                                                                                                                
                        "key" : "b",                                                                                                                                                             
                        "value" : "79219998877"                                                                                                                                                  
                },                                                                                                                                                                               
                {                                                                                                                                                                                
                        "key" : "d",                                                                                                                                                             
                        "value" : "79219998873"                                                                                                                                                  
                }                                                                                                                                                                                
        ]                                                                                                                                                                                        
}
```

Если сделать explain(), то будет видно что используются индексы.

```
"winning plan": {
    "inputStage" : {                                                 
        // INDEX SCAN!!!
        "stage" : "IXSCAN",                                      
        "keyPattern" : {                                         
                "participants.key" : 1,                          
                "participants.value" : 1                         
        },                                                       
        "indexName" : "participants.key_1_participants.value_1", 
        "isMultiKey" : true,                                     
        "direction" : "forward",                                 
        "indexBounds" : {                                        
                "participants.key" : [                           
                    "[\"a\", \"a\"]"                         
                ],                                               
                "participants.value" : [                         
                    "[\"79219998878\", \"79219998878\"]"     
                ]                                                
        }                                                        
}
```

И просто пользуетесь ей как внешним индексатором.

Да, есть оверхед, что ради этого индексатора вам придется запускать целую монгу. Но и передавать вы можете не целый документ, а только ID и массив участников. Думаю в других NoSQL БД тоже есть индексатор с требуемым функционалом и, возможно, они "легче" монги, можете использовать их.

Если уж очень хочется, то можно покопаться в исходниках монги, понять как работает такой индексатор и переписать самому. Но, по моему, оверхед на монгу дешевле чем реализация велосипеда на стероидах.

Comment: *но доступно только в MySQL*. Не только. PostgreSQL тоже это умеет.

Comment: ...только там этот тип называется не `json`, а `jsonb` и есть он в PostgreSQL 9.3+; `json` в постгресе, по большей части, просто текст и валидация.

Comment: Я примерно представляю способы решения, упирающиеся в конкретное хранилище, но сейчас я как раз пытаюсь уйти от этого. В данный момент проект сидит на реляционке, в будущем планируется переход на row-column хранилище (NoSQL - это далеко не только json-подобные хранилища), которая предполагает подготовку данных для простых запросов в "плоском" виде, и в котором я не смогу искать по части ассоциативного массива (только по полной версии). Отсюда произрастает вышеописанный вопрос, который сводится не к поиску обходных решений, а к тому, можно ли как-то представить все это в подготовленном виде.

Comment: > Отсюда произрастает вышеописанный вопрос, который сводится не к поиску обходных решений, а к тому, можно ли как-то представить все это в подготовленном виде. Тогда вопрос сводиться к "хочу алгоритм индексации с заранее неизвестным числом ключей"

Answer (score 1):

1. Можно создать таблицу с полями `a, b, conf_id, conf_date` и делать select. Идеально, если можно было бы создать еще и индекс по a и b. Без него будет долго, однако шустрее, чем прямой поиск по таблице с конференциями. Без индекса см. вариант 3.
2. Если нет индексации полей, но есть сортировка и возможность быстрого создания таблиц, можно вместо индекса создавать таблицы с названием `simulated_index_{a}_{b}`, по сути иммитация индекса. Кстати, работать будет едва ли не шустрее, чем в первом случае с индексами.
3. Если есть только возможность сортировки по произвольному полю и нет индекса, то тогда можно взять вариант 1, но добавить поле `ab`, по которому будем сортировать. ab = a*2^32 + b (тогда ab будет int64, 2^32 - размер int). Или ab = md5(a) ^ b . Ну то есть надо как-то объеденить два поля, а потом на лету вычислять нужное значение.
4. Если всё надо держать в одной таблице (которая выше), но к этой таблице можно добавлять колонки, тогда просто добавляем колонку ab из примера 3.

Я уверен, есть еще варианты. Пишите, если эти не подходят.

Comment: Боюсь, я не очень точно описал задачу. A и B могут оказаться абсолютно произвольными тегами, по факту у меня должен производиться поиск конференций, которые удовлетворяют некоторому количеству фильтров типа `присутствует участник с тегом X и значением номера Y`, т.е. `a` и `b` заранее не известны. В int32 скастовать точно не получится, это строковые данные (возможны добавочные номера и международные вызовы).

Comment: Ага, я понял. Сейчас тогда у меня два варианта: или нормализовать базу, тогда можно будет использовать индексы и делать эффективные запросы. Или создавать дерево решений (по сути - симуляция индексов). В остальных случаях вся работа будет крайне медленная, так как xml/json работают очень неэффективно, по сравнению с колонками и индексами.

Answer (score 0):

**Вариант 1.**

Если форма данных в виде JSON не принципиальна, то **в MSSQL** можно использовать дататип XML. Подробней, это очень объемная тема, можно почитать [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh403385.aspx) или, например, [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344553/how-can-i-query-a-value-in-sql-server-xml-column). К сожалению поддержку самого JSON - MS обещает только в версии 2016.

**Вариант 2.**

**В MySql** дататип JSON уже реализован (почитать можно [здесь](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html#json-paths)) что позволит вам просто хранить в поле эту конференцию и производить поиск. Однако я мало работал с MySQL и по работе с ней вряд ли подскажу что полезное. Но покопать в эту сторону вам, вероятно, будет интересно.

Comment: По xml/json полям нет индексов, значит для поиска надо будет прошерстить едва ли не всю таблицу. Ну или, если конференции отсортированы по времени, можно сократить поиск, однако это не меняет главного: если такой конференции нет, то надо проверить все записи. А это неэффективно.

Comment: @ManushinIgor, давайте начнем с начала, что вы собираетесь индексировать? В вопросе ведь нет данных о количестве данных и кроме того указана их произвольность (ненормализированность).

Comment: Если сайт уже в проде, то схема данных есть, так как поиск пойдет уже по этой схеме. Пусть схема поддерживается только у 60% данных (остальные будут в пролете сразу). В этом случае, можно для этих 60% данных развалить один json на кучу таблиц, с которыми делать join (пусть даже в памяти приложения).

Comment: @ManushinIgor, вы готовы потерять 40% информации, даже не зная сколько таких записей будет. По моему -- это именно то, что называется "преждевременной оптимизацией".

Comment: мы считаем, что записей очень много, иначе всё легче хранить в памяти приложения. Еще раз: если фильтр не сможет найти нужные поля в 40%, значит он вернет false. И самое главное - я говорю не о замене этой таблицы, а о создании дополнительных. Информация не теряется.